# How to open data which in tableView in new controller, data from FIrebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I want to send text to firebase, and then retrieve it to tableView, but some data too long and don't fit in one line, so i want that data can be open in new controller, how to release it?

My code:

```
class UserVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()
var postOneData = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Child").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let post = snapshot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = post {
        self.postData.append(actualPost)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postData.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MySell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.postData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showText", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showText" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ShowText {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a text label in you ShowText

```
private var textForShowText = String()  // a private class variable

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.textForShowText = self.postData[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showText", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showText" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ShowText {
            destinationVC.textLabel.text = textForShowText
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am assuming that your ShowText has a UITextLabel named textLabel. Also make sure that the **numberOfLines of the text label is set to 0**. You can also use a UITextView if you want !!

Comment: I'm use textView, but now it's nill, what is the problem?
https://ibb.co/ebvGh9
https://ibb.co/cgx7pp